# cassandra cluster read slow

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I have shifted from a single node to three node cluster cassandra .As per the documentation ,read latency should decrease and I should be able to fetch data more efficiently .But it is taking longer than it used to take.

RF=2 

MEMTABLE SIZE=2GB 

HEAP SIZE=8GB

I have shared the logs of the query which I ran

select * from locationinfohash where pkhash='34AAB6D5F1431151211AF721F951057F';

I can see that it read from two nodes and looking for data in memtable as well as sstables.

update 1: this trace for local_one consistency(read) and write is all
Shared two tracing session.

I am not able find out why does it take so much time to fetch the data and why is it fetching from 2 the nodes.

```
Tracing session: 2e9c6060-560b-11e9-83a5-4bbd3b5675f1

 activity                                                                                                                 | timestamp                  | source      | source_elapsed | client
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------------+----------------+-------------
                                                                                                       Execute CQL3 query | 2019-04-03 12:22:43.814000 | 10.10.10.10 |              0 | 10.10.10.10
                                         READ message received from /10.10.10.10 [MessagingService-Incoming-/10.10.10.10] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.601000 | 10.10.10.11 |             13 | 10.10.10.10
                                                       Executing single-partition query on locationinfohash [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.602000 | 10.10.10.11 |            571 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                               Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.602000 | 10.10.10.11 |            657 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 5366 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.602000 | 10.10.10.11 |            757 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 5365 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.602000 | 10.10.10.11 |            803 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 5348 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.602000 | 10.10.10.11 |            836 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 5310 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.602000 | 10.10.10.11 |            875 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 5166 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.602001 | 10.10.10.11 |            928 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 5029 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.602001 | 10.10.10.11 |            969 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 4472 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.602001 | 10.10.10.11 |           1004 | 10.10.10.10
                                                      Partition index with 5 entries found for sstable 3961 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.602001 | 10.10.10.11 |           1335 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 2660 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.603000 | 10.10.10.11 |           1876 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 2939 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.603000 | 10.10.10.11 |           1945 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 2899 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.603000 | 10.10.10.11 |           1996 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 2651 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.603000 | 10.10.10.11 |           2041 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1259 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.603000 | 10.10.10.11 |           2092 | 10.10.10.10
                                 Skipped 0/13 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.603000 | 10.10.10.11 |           2141 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Merged data from memtables and 1 sstables [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.661000 | 10.10.10.11 |          59966 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Read 1233 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.662000 | 10.10.10.11 |          60613 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                         Enqueuing response to /10.10.10.10 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.662000 | 10.10.10.11 |          60681 | 10.10.10.10
                          Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to /10.10.10.10 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/10.10.10.10-Large] | 2019-04-03 12:22:40.662000 | 10.10.10.11 |          61228 | 10.10.10.10
                                         READ message received from /10.10.10.10 [MessagingService-Incoming-/10.10.10.10] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.632000 | 10.10.10.12 |             17 | 10.10.10.10
                                                       Executing single-partition query on locationinfohash [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.633000 | 10.10.10.12 |            933 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                               Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.633000 | 10.10.10.12 |            999 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8427 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.633000 | 10.10.10.12 |           1619 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8426 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634000 | 10.10.10.12 |           2125 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8425 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634000 | 10.10.10.12 |           2168 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8424 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634000 | 10.10.10.12 |           2197 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8423 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634000 | 10.10.10.12 |           2224 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8422 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634000 | 10.10.10.12 |           2251 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8421 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634000 | 10.10.10.12 |           2290 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8420 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634001 | 10.10.10.12 |           2318 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8419 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634001 | 10.10.10.12 |           2347 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8418 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634001 | 10.10.10.12 |           2381 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8417 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634001 | 10.10.10.12 |           2409 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8416 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634001 | 10.10.10.12 |           2437 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8415 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634001 | 10.10.10.12 |           2463 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8414 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634001 | 10.10.10.12 |           2491 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8413 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634001 | 10.10.10.12 |           2519 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8412 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634001 | 10.10.10.12 |           2546 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8411 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634001 | 10.10.10.12 |           2573 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8410 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634001 | 10.10.10.12 |           2605 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8409 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634001 | 10.10.10.12 |           2633 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8408 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634002 | 10.10.10.12 |           2661 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8407 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.634002 | 10.10.10.12 |           2688 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8406 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.635000 | 10.10.10.12 |           2727 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8405 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.635000 | 10.10.10.12 |           2771 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8404 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.635000 | 10.10.10.12 |           2929 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8403 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.635000 | 10.10.10.12 |           3043 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8402 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.635000 | 10.10.10.12 |           3466 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8401 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.635000 | 10.10.10.12 |           3521 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8400 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.635001 | 10.10.10.12 |           3567 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8399 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.635001 | 10.10.10.12 |           3615 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8398 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.635001 | 10.10.10.12 |           3676 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8397 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636000 | 10.10.10.12 |           3722 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8396 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636000 | 10.10.10.12 |           3764 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8395 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636000 | 10.10.10.12 |           3810 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8394 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636000 | 10.10.10.12 |           3852 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8393 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636000 | 10.10.10.12 |           3896 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8392 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636000 | 10.10.10.12 |           3941 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8391 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636001 | 10.10.10.12 |           3979 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8390 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636001 | 10.10.10.12 |           4006 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8389 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636001 | 10.10.10.12 |           4033 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8388 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636001 | 10.10.10.12 |           4061 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8387 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636001 | 10.10.10.12 |           4105 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8386 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636001 | 10.10.10.12 |           4136 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8385 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636001 | 10.10.10.12 |           4164 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8384 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636001 | 10.10.10.12 |           4190 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8383 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636001 | 10.10.10.12 |           4217 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8382 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636002 | 10.10.10.12 |           4255 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8381 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636002 | 10.10.10.12 |           4282 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8380 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636002 | 10.10.10.12 |           4311 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8379 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636002 | 10.10.10.12 |           4338 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8378 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636002 | 10.10.10.12 |           4380 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 8348 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636002 | 10.10.10.12 |           4424 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 7781 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636002 | 10.10.10.12 |           4475 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 7253 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.636002 | 10.10.10.12 |           4520 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 6704 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.637000 | 10.10.10.12 |           5603 | 10.10.10.10
                                                      Partition index with 5 entries found for sstable 6223 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.638000 | 10.10.10.12 |           5757 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 4263 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.641000 | 10.10.10.12 |           9393 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 4598 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.641000 | 10.10.10.12 |           9470 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 4258 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.641000 | 10.10.10.12 |           9503 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 4265 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.641001 | 10.10.10.12 |           9532 | 10.10.10.10
                                 Skipped 0/59 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.641001 | 10.10.10.12 |           9562 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Merged data from memtables and 1 sstables [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.708000 | 10.10.10.12 |          76713 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                  Read 1233 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.709000 | 10.10.10.12 |          77406 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                         Enqueuing response to /10.10.10.10 [ReadStage-7] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.709000 | 10.10.10.12 |          77503 | 10.10.10.10
                          Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to /10.10.10.10 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/10.10.10.10-Large] | 2019-04-03 12:22:42.710000 | 10.10.10.12 |          78298 | 10.10.10.10
 Parsing select * from locationinfohash WHERE pkhash = '118BF26BD7FDF182DEC316296A8B1945'; [Native-Transport-Requests-20] | 2019-04-03 12:22:43.814000 | 10.10.10.10 |            101 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                       Preparing statement [Native-Transport-Requests-20] | 2019-04-03 12:22:43.814000 | 10.10.10.10 |            157 | 10.10.10.10
                                                            reading data from /10.10.10.11 [Native-Transport-Requests-20] | 2019-04-03 12:22:43.814000 | 10.10.10.10 |            433 | 10.10.10.10
                                                    speculating read retry on /10.10.10.12 [Native-Transport-Requests-20] | 2019-04-03 12:22:43.815000 | 10.10.10.10 |            521 | 10.10.10.10
                                      Sending READ message to /10.10.10.11 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/10.10.10.11-Small] | 2019-04-03 12:22:43.815000 | 10.10.10.10 |            573 | 10.10.10.10
                                      Sending READ message to /10.10.10.12 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/10.10.10.12-Small] | 2019-04-03 12:22:43.815000 | 10.10.10.10 |            594 | 10.10.10.10
                             REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /10.10.10.11 [MessagingService-Incoming-/10.10.10.11] | 2019-04-03 12:22:43.880000 | 10.10.10.10 |          65915 | 10.10.10.10
                                                           Processing response from /10.10.10.11 [RequestResponseStage-9] | 2019-04-03 12:22:43.880000 | 10.10.10.10 |          66069 | 10.10.10.10
                             REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /10.10.10.12 [MessagingService-Incoming-/10.10.10.12] | 2019-04-03 12:22:43.905000 | 10.10.10.10 |            145 | 10.10.10.10
                                                           Processing response from /10.10.10.12 [RequestResponseStage-2] | 2019-04-03 12:22:43.906000 | 10.10.10.10 |            270 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                          Initiating read-repair [RequestResponseStage-2] | 2019-04-03 12:22:43.906000 | 10.10.10.10 |            329 | 10.10.10.10
                                                                                                         Request complete | 2019-04-03 12:22:43.892987 | 10.10.10.10 |          78987 | 10.10.10.10
```

Edit 1:

```
CREATE TABLE trackfleet_db.locationinfohash (
    pkhash text,
    gpsdt timestamp,
    dt timestamp,
    gpsdtt bigint,
    id text,
    lastgpsdt timestamp,
    latitude double,
    longitude double,
    odo int,
    odometer int,
    port int,
    speed int,
    srtangle int,
    stats map<text, int>,
    stoppageflag int,
    PRIMARY KEY (pkhash, gpsdt)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (gpsdt ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy', 'compaction_window_size': '1', 'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: How far away are these nodes located? How are they communicating?

Comment: Also, this `As per the documentation ,read latency should decrease and I should be able to fetch data more efficiently` may be a bit misleading. Yes, you may get better read performance due to less load on individual nodes and data locality. But it's not always true that more nodes == better performance. What's your consistency level?

Comment: @NestorSokil these nodes are located on same server and they communicating via ring model used in cassandra forming a cluster, consistency level for write is quorum and read is also quorum

Comment: But have you checked the inter-node latency. In your logs 10.11 sent the response `07:31:50.663000` and 10.10 received it at 07:31:51.789000. Assuming clocks are in sync, it's a whole second to respond to coordinator.

Comment: What is the primary key definition?  Also, are the column values in these rows ever updated?  If so, how often?  If this is a query by secondary index, then moving to a plural node environment will be slower.  Also, if the partitions have a large amount of obsoleted data (from in-place updates), that will slow things down as well.

Comment: You should try with consistency ONE it will improve the results. For high latency reason may be multiple like large partition, sstable count. etc.

Comment: @LetsNoSQL tried this with consistency level one but read latency were high and I am not able to understand that when reading the data,why it comes from two node where one node consist of replica ,when I have PK ideally it should be read from a single node then why it returned the data from other node..doesnt it beat the purpose of whole pk? correct me if I get it wrong

Comment: @Aaron primary key is a md5 of id+date . The rows hardly get update.There is no secondary index .I have updated the question with table schema . One thing that I am confused about is why is data coming from 2 nodes.Other node just contains the replica of it. when I have PK ideally it should be read from a single node then why it returned the data from other node..doesnt it beat the purpose of whole pk? correct me if I get it wrong

Comment: "One thing that I am confused about is why is data coming from 2 nodes?"  Because you are reading at QUORUM.  Quorum of 2 is 2.

Comment: @NestorSokil there is difference of 1200ms between two servers

Comment: @Aaron even when I was reading with consistency one it was reading from both nodes. That is why it was confusing

Comment: If you're not using the `TokenAwareLoadBalancingPolicy` it will designate one node as a coordinator node.  It's either that, or you're not setting LOCAL_ONE when you think you are.

Comment: @Aaron I am sure about setting read consistency to local_one ,ran the query again but same reading from two nodes, how do I set/deal with this 'TokenAwareLoadBalancingPolicy'  .

Comment: So since the clocks are off... can you tell us how long does the query take? From what I can see, it’s about 450 ms? I can easily imagine this performance on slow HDD + network overhead

Comment: @Aaron please help me clear this thing out that if I am not using application to connect to cassandra,as far as I can understand your point on TokenAwareLoadBalancingPolicy ,which is builtin to drivers. How will this help me with the above trace. so if I use the query on cqlsh, it  is still fetching me the data from two nodes as above ,murmur3partitioner works in the background for even distribution.Point me if I am wrong. Main question is why is data coming from two nodes.Please help.

Comment: @experiment This is what official docs say about read ONE: `Returns a response from the closest replica, as determined by the snitch. By default, a read repair runs in the background to make the other replicas consistent.` https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html

Comment: @NestorSokil yes but why is it reading from two nodes when the other node just contains the replica of it. It should ideally read from one node to fetch the data

Comment: @experiment what I'm assuming is that it may be reading from another replica to determine if it needs to catch up with read-repair

Comment: @NestorSokil could be the reason, percentage repaired in my condition for one node is 78% .How can we make sure that it could be a problem.

Comment: @experiment try setting read_repair_chance = 0 and dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0 and test queries again

Comment: @NestorSokil what impact will it have,does it stops the repair?

Comment: @NestorSokil  "A query with a consistency level of ONE or LOCAL_ONE can't cause a blocking read repair because we must have a data mismatch to trigger the read repair and if we only queried one replica, there's no comparison, so no mismatch. " and I am reading with local_one,then also it fetches from two nodes. I am not able to understand how?

Comment: @experiment yes, it turns off read repair. and whether it's ok for you or not is up to you, but if you want to know if that's the reason then you should try disabling it.

Comment: @experiment and are you sure that the read from the second replica is blocking in your case? As I understand the logs you posted are with consistency QUORUM. Maybe post logs when running with ONE?

Comment: @NestorSokil updated the question with new logs with consistency local_one

Comment: @experiment see that in the new logs `Initiating read-repair` has a later timestamp than `Request complete`?

Comment: @NestorSokil yes I have pasted the whole log as it is.